# Football teams league

Tags: python, python-itertools

Imagine I have 3 teams, and I want to generate random matches between the three teams. I used itertools permutations to print all matches. The problem is generating a score in a game. Imagine team A vs team B (2-1). How do I input the 2 goals by team A and 1 goal by team B in a match?

I have printed all possible matches. Note that I used permutations because Team A vs Team B is different from Team B vs Team A because one team plays at home, and in another game plays at the other team's home.

```
import itertools
import random

teams=['A','B','C']

def games():
  permutations=itertools.permutations(teams,2)
  for i in permutations:
    print(i)
    result=random.randint(0,5)
```

My doubt is when I have to generate a result in a game in every iteration.

Comment: Do you need to store each game result? If so, you should think about how you want your data to be structured.

Comment: yes but that part i think i will handle. Victory equals 3 points draw 1 point

Answer (score 2):

You are generating a single integer, but you need two to represent a match score:

```
import itertools
import random

teams = ['A','B','C']

def games():
    permutations = itertools.permutations(teams, 2)
    for match in permutations:
        home_team_score, away_team_score = random.randint(0, 5), random.randint(0, 5)
        print(match, home_team_score, away_team_score)

games()
```

Sample output

```
('A', 'B') 4 2
('A', 'C') 0 1
('B', 'A') 2 5
('B', 'C') 1 2
('C', 'A') 2 4
('C', 'B') 1 1
```

Then you can play around with the format, for example

```
for (home_team, away_team) in permutations:
    home_team_score, away_team_score = random.randint(0, 5), random.randint(0, 5)
    print('{} {} - {} {}'.format(home_team, home_team_score, away_team_score, away_team))
```

to get

```
A 4 - 4 B
A 0 - 4 C
B 3 - 4 A
B 1 - 0 C
C 2 - 1 A
C 3 - 5 B
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
import random

teams=['A','B','C']

def make_games():
    games=[]
    permutations=itertools.permutations(teams,2)
    for team_tuple in permutations:
        game={}
        team_one, team_two = team_tuple[0],team_tuple[1]
        team_one_score, team_two_score=random.randint(0,5),random.randint(0,5)
        game[team_one]=team_one_score
        game[team_two]=team_two_score
        games.append(game)
    return games

print(make_games())
```

Out:

```
[
{'A': 1, 'B': 4}, 
{'A': 1, 'C': 0}, 
{'B': 5, 'A': 1}, 
{'B': 1, 'C': 1}, 
{'C': 1, 'A': 5}, 
{'C': 2, 'B': 3}
]
```

Comment: what is the turtle for ?

Comment: I just like turtles

Comment: You don't want to have a function and a variable with the same name

Comment: yeah, sorry I was just trying to beat you to the answer. I'll change it